# Secure Data Transfer Between Websites

Tags: post, ssl, web

I want to securely send form data from one website to a website on a different server.

For security, I think I should be using SSL. From what I understand, I just need to install OpenSSL on both servers and they will send data with it. Is this correct? Is this security sufficient for personal information?

To send the data, do I use "POST" like when sending data to local files? If so, how do I reference the remote file to handle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not correct that you only need to install OpenSSL, but you also need to configure the webserver to use HTTPS. Next to that, you will need to set up the form to use the HTTPS connection by making sure that you put https://www.example.com instead of http://www.example.com.

If you also need valid SSL certificates, you can find various providers e.g. https://www.startssl.com. Or if this is for private or configured use you can use self-signed certificates, google is your friend.